# Checking whether value exists in an array of objects without using INCLUDES

Tags: javascript, html

*Note on title: I really did not know how to perfectly name this question. If someone can suggest a more appropriate title, please do.*

I have a table where headers must be colored based on the first 7 characters of their name.

First 7 characters are *yyyy.mm*. For example 2017.10.

**Here is my need:**

- I want every occurrence of same 7 chars to be the same color (cell's background color). In other words, if cell's first 7 chars are 2017.10 - they all should be the same color. If it is 2017.09, they all should be the same color BUT different from 2017.10 or any other date.

I am trying to do it but having really hard time finishing it. I feel like I am close...

**JS:**

```js
function setHeaderColor() {
  const mainTable = document.getElementById('main-table');
  const headerRow = document.querySelectorAll('#main-table tr:first-child th');
  const test = []; // Holds first 7 chars and background color of each column header
  const colors = [
    '#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF', '#FFFF99', '#00B3E6',
    '#E6B333', '#3366E6', '#999966', '#99FF99', '#B34D4D',
    '#80B300', '#809900', '#E6B3B3', '#6680B3', '#66991A',
    '#FF99E6', '#CCFF1A', '#FF1A66', '#E6331A', '#33FFCC',
    '#66994D', '#B366CC', '#4D8000', '#B33300', '#CC80CC',
    '#66664D', '#991AFF', '#E666FF', '#4DB3FF', '#1AB399',
    '#E666B3', '#33991A', '#CC9999', '#B3B31A', '#00E680',
    '#4D8066', '#809980', '#E6FF80', '#1AFF33', '#999933',
    '#FF3380', '#CCCC00', '#66E64D', '#4D80CC', '#9900B3',
    '#E64D66', '#4DB380', '#FF4D4D', '#99E6E6', '#6666FF'
  ];

  headerRow[1].style.backgroundColor = colors[1];

  // Extract first 7 characters from column header name
  for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
    test.push({
      version: headerRow[i].innerHTML.substring(0, 7),
      color: headerRow[i].style.backgroundColor || null
    });
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (test[i].version === test[i - 1].version) {
      test[i].color = test[i - 1].color
    } else {
      test[i].color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
    headerRow[i].style.backgroundColor = test[i].color;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setHeaderColor);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<table class="w3-table-all" id="main-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="w3-center"> Name</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.10-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709.</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.09-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709.</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.10-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.09-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709</th>
    <th class="w3-center">2017.08-T-2018_08_30 ms_201709</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, every time colors are different. What I am doing now is comparing cell to the previous cell (`[i - 1]`). I know I should be checking whether this value exists in an array `test` and then getting its associated color, but I cannot come up with a way to do that. I tried `indexOf`, `includes` and no success...

Comment: You seem to be asking 2 separate questions here 1) How to set the colors correctly 2) how to persist the colors between sessions. I don't see any attempt at #2. What have you tried. Also, you say *I want every occurrence of same 7 chars to be the same color.* Foreground or back? If one cell contains two values, it can only have one background color. Please clarify.

Comment: If you want the colors to be saved, than you need to use localStorage

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ok, I deleted 2nd question completely. I need to color cell's background - exactly how I am doing it right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey No it is not. I already mentioned that I tried using `includes`

Comment: There are 43 answers on that question, [including one that makes no mention of `includes` or `indexOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953622/215552)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just create a lookup table, if the key exists return it, if it does not grab a new color.

```js
const colors = ['#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF', '#FFFF99', '#00B3E6']
const used = {}
function getColor (key) {
  used[key] = used[key] || colors.shift()
  return used[key]
}

console.log("aaa", getColor("aaa"))
console.log("bbb", getColor("bbb"))
console.log("aaa", getColor("aaa"))
console.log("bbb", getColor("bbb"))
```

How to store it, use localStorage

```js
// default color list
const colors = ['#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF', '#FFFF99', '#00B3E6']
// read local storage, if empty, than use empty object
const used = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("used") || "{}")
// remove any colors used already so we do not reuse them
Object.values(used).forEach(cc => {
  // find it in the array
  const ind = colors.indexOf(cc)
  // if found, remove it
  if (ind > -1 ) {
    colors.splice(ind, 1)
  }
})

function getColor (key) {
  // check if we have it, if not grab a new one
  used[key] = used[key] || colors.shift()
  // return the code
  return used[key]
}

console.log("aaa", getColor("aaa"))
console.log("bbb", getColor("bbb"))
console.log("aaa", getColor("aaa"))
console.log("bbb", getColor("bbb"))
console.log("bbb", getColor("ccc"))

// set the localstorage with the used values
localStorage.setItem("used", JSON.stringify(used))
```

Comment: I don't quite get the `key`... What do you pass as the `key`?

Comment: Because that is what you wanted! "2017.09" is one..... "2017.10" is another.... etc

Comment: What I am asking is what should I pass as the key in my case. In other words, can you give me an example that relates to MY code. I can't understand how to combine what you answered with what I have. Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm:) Thanks a lot. I did not even use storage part, and the colors are always the same. I close window, come back, and colors are same. What is the difference than between leaving it as it is or using your approach of storing them on local storage?

Comment: well do the dates get removed over time? Than the colors will eventually change..... If you do it randomly like you did before than it would need to be stored.

Comment: No, the dates do not get removed. They only get added. I think I can just leave it as it is - without local storage

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to look up whether you've previously assigned a color value to a yyyy.mm string. The best data structure for this sort of lookup is a map, not an array.

In Javascript it's pretty common to use objects as hash maps:

```js
const colorMap = {};
const colors = ['#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF']

// use this function by passing in your "yyyy.mm" strings 
function getColorFor(firstSevenChars) {
    if(colorMap[firstSevenChars] !== undefined) {
         // we've encountered this character combo before! 
         // retrieve the corresponding color.
         return colorMap[firstSevenChars];
    }
   
    // get the next free color, which is the n+1th color, 
    // n being the number of colours already assigned.
    // use modulo (%) to ensure that we don't exceed the colors array.
    let newColor = colors[ Object.keys(colorMap).length % colors.length ];
     
    // associate the yyyy.mm code with the new color and return it.
    colorMap[firstSevenChars] = newColor;
    return newColor;
}

console.log("2018.01", getColorFor("2018.01"));
console.log("2018.02", getColorFor("2018.02"));
console.log("2018.03", getColorFor("2018.03"));
console.log("out of colors! loop through them again...");
console.log("2018.04", getColorFor("2018.04"));
console.log("2018.05", getColorFor("2018.05"));
```

Comment: Problem is that 2018.01 and 2018.04 have the same color. I want them to be different. But if there was another 2018.01 - it should have #FF6633

Comment: So long as you provide more colors than you have yyyy.mm values, you'll have a new color every time! The modulo is just prevents your code from erroring if you have a large number of different yyyy.mm values

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an inner for loop which will find all the matching versions and set the colour.

change the loop to the following.

```
for (let i = 1; i < test.length; i++) {
    for(let j=i;j<test.length; j++){
        if (test[i].version === test[j].version) {
          test[i].color = test[j].color
        } else {
          test[i].color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
    }
}
```